# Print User Registration Block Through template.php file

Tags: blocks, users

I just want to print the user registration block through my template.php file without using the [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) or Enabling php on my site to use this code:

```
<?php

if(user_is_anonymous()) {  
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  print drupal_render($form);
}

?>
```

I have tried the following:

```
function my_template_form_alter {

      $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
      print drupal_render($form);
}
```

I want this block to appear on my blocks administration page just like the user login block, so I can place it anywhere I like. Any help as per how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't need any alters. Just go to the template in which you want to place the registration form and add,

```
$form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
print drupal_render($form);
```

This will print the user registration form. It's always good to have a check for anonymous users as a wrapper of this output.

Edit #1 (After question update and comments)
I suppose you want to create a block that will appear in your "admin/structure/block" page and you can assign the block in any desired region? - Right? I don't think your question says the same but this can be done in the following way,

- Create a hook_block_info() & hook_block_view()
- In the hook_block_view() assign the "content" the following,

```
$form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
$block['content'] = drupal_render($form);
```

I hope this can solve your problem. I haven't tested this yet!

Comment: Apologies, i did not add the function wrapper where this goes to, what function do i add this to? like: function my_templatename_form_alter

Comment: no, just add this in your tpl.php file. That will do.

Comment: I want this block to appear as one of the blocks in my blocks administration page, so i can place it anywhere i want

Comment: Ahh, then you should update your question. Currently it's not clear what you need to do. So please update it so that others can suggest some options too.